# How can I use commands in a listlisting

Tags: listings

I have the following latex code

```
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=\%]
begin
  begin
    \alpha;
    i = 5

  ...
\end{lstlisting}
```

and I would like to have the `\alpha` be rendered as a `⍺` but it seems to still render as `\alpha`. How can I get it to render as a `⍺`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look up `Escaping to LaTeX` in the `listings` manual

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can typeset maths using LaTeX code in a `lstlisting` environment when setting the key `mathescape` as `true`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=\%, mathescape=true]
begin
  begin
    $\alpha$;
    i = 5

  ...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are other ways to achieve similar results. As said by @daleif in the comments, it is described in more details in the section *Escaping to LaTeX* of `listings`'s [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings).